# I accidentally called a function without its parameters but my code still works?

Tags: python

I was going through my old code and I have no idea how I was able to call gradientMaker on line 139 without passing it an argument. gradientMaker isn’t used anywhere else in the code. Does anyone know how it's possible to call a function without it's parameters?

[picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvlvE.png)

Comment: Post code as text, not a picture. We can't search pictures.

Comment: You don't actually call the function. Instead, you assign the function to `xcolor`. Since your code works, one can only assume that `xcolor` is supposed to hold a function object. We don't see what happens to `xcolor` next, so can't comment on that.

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of the code. Paste the code.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you haven't called `gradientMaker`. You have just passed a reference of it to the `xcolor` variable.

To call the function you need to use parenthesis -

```
gradientMaker()
```

Answer (score 1):

- You are not calling the function. There's are no `()` at the end.
- What you are doing now is just assigning that function reference to variable `xcolour`